# Where are the matchers in gtest?

Tags: googletest

In [gtest's online documentation](https://google.github.io/googletest/reference/matchers.html) there's mention of matchers and there's a whole slew of them (e.g. `ElementsAre`) but I don't see them at all in gtest's [actual code](https://github.com/google/googletest/tree/main/googletest/include/gtest). So, where are they? Further, I can't see even the macro `ASSERT_THAT` that's supposed to be used with the matchers.

Answer (score 1):

They're not in `googletest/include/gtest/gtest-matchers.h`, they're in `googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h`.